# Anchors for recent activity not landing on the supposed location for questions with numerous answers

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

When clicking this link:
[image: sample question link]

I land here:

[image: landing above the correct area]

While the URL indicates I should land about 3 screen heights lower.
If you go back using your browser button and then click the link again you land on the right location. This suggests some sort of caching or lazy loading might be the culprit.
This happens most commonly in questions with multiple answers. It might be that the space reserved for images is on average too little, so that once the images are loaded the page has shifted within its frame.

This behaviour is both reported to occur in FireFox and Chrome latest stable versions.

Comment: This isn't just anchors for recent activity: It's basically any link to any post on a page with a lot of images in the posts above them, and it also seems to depend a bit on your internet connection speed how many images is 'too many'. I've seen it with moderator flags, or with people sharing links to their answers on winterbash/swag contest posts too.