# Hat display bug

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2020

My "hat" is shown twice in my answer, once in my sig, and again above.

MacOS 10.14.6; Safari Version 14.0.2 (14610.3.7.1.10)

> [image: hat image]

Comment: noticed that multiple times, now I know this isn't just a local issue due to my specific browser.

Comment: Seems to happen when I reload the page

Comment: What browser / operating system are you on?

Comment: Does it happen on all sites, or only on Math (it seems?)?

Comment: @nohillside seen that one happen on this site too.

Comment: Also Math.meta  II checked some other sites where I have answers, but did not find the bug anywhere other than these

Comment: Maybe just on Safari?

Comment: Reproduced on chrome on android. Related to this bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357638/anchors-for-recent-activity-not-landing-on-the-supposed-location-for-questions-w I think.

Comment: Reproduced on Seamonkey (which is based on Firefox ESR).  Everything looked correct initially but when the title to [this linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307227/for-f-convex-and-lambda-i0-sum-lambda-i-1-x-i-in-mathbbr-does?noredirect=1&lq=1) finished rendering a second hat got displayed.  Maybe something to do with LATEX formatting in titles?

Comment: Chrome bug which is related. Run snipplet and the hat sits in middle of snipplet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pedi6.png

Comment: Same. Chrome, Android. Got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB4cJ.jpg

Comment: Unrelated but why are you considered a new contributor? You've been a member for almost a decade

Comment: @BlockofDiamond Users are considered **new contributors** until they post a certain number of **posts**.  So being new **contributors** doesn't really mean they're new **users**.

Comment: @Ak. But 9 years, and `new contributor` just sounds wrong

Comment: @BlockofDiamond This was my first post to meta.stackexchange, so I am a "new contributor".

Comment: @nohillside I just saw it on Workplace too, so not only isn't it just Math but it isn't fixed yet either.

Comment: I have the same bug on MacOS Big Sur Google Chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed. Hats are no longer duplicated in this circumstance.

Big Shout out to [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) for his help fixing this (and earning a `Defender of the Unicorn` hat in the process).

> do something on page
> no longer seeing double
> big thanks to balpha!

Comment: Wearing it with pride!